# Regex to delete lines that contain | in node.js

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a txt file that contains:

```
   | Addresses          |           
   | App Settings       |           
   | Contact Us         |           
   | Do Not Sell My Personal Information |
```

I Want to delete all lines that contain the '|' character.

I have a regex that is taking out certain keywords from my files in Node.js but I can' figure out how to take out the '|' character itself.

This is my regex so far `textfile.replace(/^.*[@].*|.*Examples.*|.*Scenario.*|.*Feature.*/gm, "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `|` has special meaning in the regexp, you need to escape it or put it in `[]` to match it literally. So you can add it to the `[@]` character set.

```
textfile.replace(/.*([@|]|Examples|Scenario|Feature).*/g, "")
```

However, this leaves blank lines in place of the removed lines.

To remove entire lines that match the pattern, it would be easier to convert the string to an array, then filter the array using the pattern, rather than doing the entire thing with a regexp.

```
let lines = textfile.split('\n')
let filtered_lines = lines.filter(line => !/[@|]|Examples|Scenario|Feature/.test(line))
let result = filtered_lines.join('\n');
```

Comment: This regex leaves empty lines instead of deleting them

Comment: @TheZver Thanks, I've updated it to show how to do this by filtering an array of lines instead of regexp replace.